# UploadField for Files in SilverStripe

Tags: file-upload, silverstripe

I want to insert a new field, below the content textarea, to hold a link/connection to one file (moastly a zip file from my assets folder).

I couldn't find any documentation nor a tutorial for files. Only images. Does anybody know where I can find some help files or can give me some basic code to start from?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In general, there's the [API Docs for UploadField](http://api.silverstripe.org/3.0/framework/forms/UploadField.html).
As well as the [docs](http://doc.silverstripe.org/framework/en/reference/uploadfield),
although they're a bit hidden - I'm just fixing the search on doc.silverstripe.org.

This should do the trick:

```
<?php
class Page extends SiteTree {
    static $has_one = array('MyFile', 'File');
    function getCMSFields() {
        $fields = parent::getCMSFields();
        $upload = new UploadField('MyFile');
        $upload->setConfig('allowedMaxFileNumber', 1);
        $upload->getValidator()->setAllowedExtensions(array('zip'));
        $fields->addFieldToTab('Root.Main', $upload);
        return $fields;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I am afraid, I am late for my reply. Didn't get an mail by stackoverflow. Anyway, got it working :-)